# Dependency Injection in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a controller

```
@Controller
public class AppController{

   @Autowired
   private IDemoApplicationService service;
   //more code

}
```

Service

```
@Service("service")
public class DemoApplicationServiceImpl implements IDemoApplicationService{
    @Override
public void createEmployee(Employee employee){  
    try {
        dao.insertEmployee(employee);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public String updateEmployee(Employee employee, int id) {
    dao.updateEmployee(employee, id);
    return "redirect:/employees";
}

@Override
public String deleteEmployee(int id) {
    dao.deleteEmployee(id);
    return "redirect:/employees";
}

@Override
public String getEmployees(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employees", dao.getEmployees());
    return "employees";
}

@Override
public Employee findById(int id) {
    return dao.findById(id);
}
}
```

Service Interface

```
public interface IDemoApplicationService {

}
```

I want to use @Autowired in my controller to use the service but when I run the application I get the following error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private services.IDemoApplicationService
>   controllers.DemoApplication.service; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [services.IDemoApplicationService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Can anyone tell me what should I do to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have your controller annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: It is a springboot application

Comment: That hasn't answered my question. Why is your **controller** annotated with that?

Comment: This is my first spring boot application I am following this tutorial http://sfdcworkshop.com/workshop/heroku-connect/hc-java-spring-jdbc/ and in the controller here is annotated with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Check the complete example [here](https://github.com/rajdeepd/heroku-connect-spring-boot-jdbc-rw/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/HerokuConnectApplication.java). You need to define main method to start the springboot application then controller and services classes are configured.

Comment: You can also check another example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)

Comment: I have checked this but I wanted to create a service layer and the main controller should use the service instead of doing the business logic in controller

Comment: I have the main method in the controller

Comment: How does your project structure look like?

Comment: Probably `ComponentScan` could be the problem. Show the package structure

Comment: @Wearybands How are you getting `dao` object in ServiceImpl? That might be the point of concern? Otherwise your code looks good now.

Comment: EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside `@SpringBootApplication` it contains a lot of another Spring's annotations

Some of them:

```
1)@Configuration

2)@ComponentScan
```

In @SpringBootApplication you can path a param:

```
@AliasFor(annotation = ComponentScan.class, attribute = "basePackages")
    public String[] scanBasePackages() default {};
```

As you can see it's alias for `@ComponentScan` to know which packages to scan for classes anotated with @Component or sub annotations like `@Service @Repository`  if you don't provide this param , Spring will scan main package where class annotated with SpringBootApplication is lokated.

Most probably your service locate in a differente package

Answer (score 0):

Your `DemoApplication` is your application start-up class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

Then you need to have a separate controller file as follows:

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private IDemoApplicationService service;
    //more code
}

@Service("service")
public class DemoApplicationServiceImpl implements IDemoApplicationService{

}
```

**Why you need to make above changes:**

`@SpringBootApplication` is equivalent to using three separate annotations i.e. `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration`. You can read more about this at [Using Spring Boot Docs.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

When you provide `@Controller` before `@SpringBootApplication`, `@Configuration` part does not get chance to register beans in the context and hence you are getting the said error.

Comment: Error creating bean with name appcontroller

Comment: @Wearybands What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: services.DemoApplicationServiceImpl controllers.AppController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [services.DemoApplicationServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: @Wearybands Made changes to my code. You need to Autowire using the service interface and provide the reference name in `@Service` annotation

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private services.IDemoApplicationService controllers.AppController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [services.IDemoApplicationService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: Do I need any xml file to define my beans, its my first springboot application btw

Comment: @Wearybands No, you do not need to have an XML file. Is there any Autowired bean within Service implementation like any repository?